# What is the right way to set attachments path in nodeMailer?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, nodemailer

I'am a newbie of Nodejs world. I want to send an email with embedded image. But my image didn't show in email. I thought it might be about my file path setting. Here is my mailOptions,

```
    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'mymail@gmail.com',
        to: to,
        subject: subject,
        html: html,
        attachments: [{
            filename: "logo.png",
            filePath: "/images/logo.png",
            cid: "logo-mail"
        }]
    };
```

And my directory that keeps my static files is

```
myproject/
         assets/
               images/
               js/
               styles/
```

And this is my html,

```
<img src="cid:logo-mail" />
```

Here is my result in an email,

```
<img src="cid.php?mid=e_ZGHjAQV4ZQLlAGNkZQNjZGN1AQt3Zt==&amp;pj=logo-mail" alt="cid.php?mid=e_ZGHjAQV4ZQLlAGNkZQNjZGN1AQ">
```

I am not sure that am I right to set file path like this ?

```
filePath: "/images/logo.png"
```

Answer (score 3):

I did like this

```
filePath: process.cwd() + "/assets/images/logo.png"
```

And now it's working !

Thanks everyone for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You need full path to your image

```
http://www.example.com/images/logo.png
```

since i could read your email on gmail.com the relative path would be translated to

```
gmail.com/images/logo.png
```

Comment: Can I use it with my local ? something like this, http://localhost:1337/images/logo.png

Comment: Yes it should work. If the image shows up when you type that address into browser then you know it works right? :)

Comment: Remember that it will only work for you. Nobody else can access your locahost.